# Python Asynchronous websockets class: __aenter__ access

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket

I have an asynchronous API which I'm using to connect to WebSocket and make some request:

## main.py

```
import asyncio
from .websocket import AsynWebsocket as aw

class Api(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def main(self):
        async with aw() as websocket:

            self.aw_con = websocket

            # Normal request
            request = {"id_color": '#EA1010'}
            await self.aw_con.send(request)
            print(await self.aw_con.receive())

            # Function request
            color = await self.get_new_color(request)
            print(color)

    async def get_new_color(self, request):
        await self.aw_con.send(request)
        return await self.aw_con.receive()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = Api()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(st.main())
```

## websocket.py

```
import asyncio
from websockets import connect

class AsynWebsocket(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.conn = connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        self.websocket = await self.conn.__aenter__()        
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        await self.conn.__aexit__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def send(self, message):
        await self.websocket.send(message)

    async def receive(self):
        return await self.websocket.recv()
```

When I try to access `main` function everything goes well:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = Api()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Send request and receive respones
    loop.run_until_complete(st.main())
```

I would like to access `get_new_color` function of my class bypassing `main` and still be able to send the request:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = Api()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # This fails
    request = {"id_color" : '#EA1010'}
    loop.run_until_complete(st.get_new_color(request))
```

It shows me an error: `conn` variable is not declared because it doesn't enter the `__aenter__` function where a declaration is made. Is there any other way to access `__aenter__` and send the request without using `async with` in every function? How can I call class function outside and make send request working?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code (though it's possible this is due to my ignorance of asyncio). Do you mean for `API.main` to be calling `send()` and `receive()` on `self` (where they don't seem to be defined), or on `websocket` (where they are)?

Comment: Why are you even wrapping the websocket? Your class is nothing more than a proxy for the existing `websocket` client there.

Comment: @Blckknght you are right, I was missing websocket declaration on self, question updated

Comment: @MartijnPieters I want to create long live connection for main() where I will do things with my requests, but in some case, I would like to access my class function outside of the loop and still be able to send requests (new connection will be created).

Comment: @Steve: Then my second revision of my answer will give you exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `Api()` for ad-hoc websocket calls, you could establish a connection on demand. Perhaps you could make the `Api` *itself* an async context manager, one that sets up the connection if one is not already established:

```
class Api(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._aw_conn = None
        self._depth = 0

    async def __aenter__(self):
        # create a connection *if not already established*
        if self._aw_conn is None:
            self._aw_conn = await connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")
            self._depth = 0
        self._depth += 1
        return self._aw_conn

    async def __aexit__(self, *exc_info):
        self._depth -= 1
        if self._depth < 1:
            # close the connection
            await self._aw_conn.close()
            self._aw_conn = None
            self._depth = 0

    async def main(self):
        async with self as websocket:
            # Normal request
            request = {"id_color": '#EA1010'}
            await websocket.send(request)
            print(await self.websocket.receive())

            # Function request
            color = await self.get_new_color(request)
            print(color)

    async def get_new_color(self, request):
        async with self as websocket:
            await self.aw_con.send(request)
            return await websocket.receive()
```

Now the `Api()` class manages **one** websocket, that is reused each time you use the instance as a context manager. This means that in `Api().main()` you get a websocket for the direct calls, and the `self.get_new_color()` re-uses that already established socket.

But for a `Api().get_new_color()` call there is no websocket yet and it is established only then.

Comment: I think you want `self._aw_conn = None` instead of `self._depth = 0` in `__aexit__`. The depth is already zero, that's why you've closing the socket. You need to remove the reference to the socket that was closed, or you won't be able to reuse the `Api` instance (it won't connect again if `_aw_conn` is not `None`).

Comment: @Blckknght: Ack, I indeed need to set the connection to none too. The `depth` setting is defensive coding, you could accidentally use the same `Api()` instance in two tasks and the `await` lets you switch to the other.